# how to restart mongodb container after config changes

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

We have mongodb running as container on K8S, and while trying to connect this mongodb from a pod we are getting an exception below.

```
state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.0.62.187:30007, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
2020-12-24 06:17:48.931  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-12-24 06:17:48.940  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='5fe4326e6540422545cf4267', description='null'}-<IP>:30007] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.9/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
 java.base@11.0.9/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
 java.base@11.0.9
```

I did some config changes ( modified bind-ip to 0.0.0.0)in /etc/mongod.conf.orig since i could not find /etc/mongod.conf file , and wanted to restart the mongodb container.

How to restart this container with the config changed saved.

Comment: If you edit files directly inside containers, your changes _will_ get lost.  In Kubernetes in particular, the cluster can decide that it needs to delete a pod and recreate it on a different node without asking or telling you.  Inject the file using a ConfigMap instead.

Comment: Yeah , i did using configmap like below but no luck.edited the configmap like following and restarted the mongodb pod , but still my application container failed with exception.                                                                             mongo.conf: |
    storage:
      dbPath: /data/db
    net:
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:

Answer (score 0):

If your MongoDB is deployed as K8s Deployment, plus you are not worried about **downtime**, simply delete the Pods and they will get recreated.

For an **interruption-free restart** by Kubernetes, make an non-invasive change to your Deployment or StatefulSet yaml, e.g. add a label or environment variable and K8s will do the restart of all Pods for you.

Comment: i tried deleting the mongo pod, but the /etc/mongod.conf.orig (inside container), changes(bind-ip to 0.0.0.0 are not saved and fallen back to default(127.0.0.1).

Comment: You have to extract the configuration to a config map and mount it into your container.

Comment: edited the configmap like following and restarted the mongodb pod , but still my application container failed with exception.                                                                             mongo.conf: |
    storage:
      dbPath: /data/db
    net:
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: